# MEAN.io application not starting

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, single-page-application, mean-stack

I am trying to teach myself how to use the MEAN stack and I am working through the docs from the MEAN.io site. I am at the point where I run the following commands:

```
$ npm install -g mean-cli
$ mean init <myApp>
$ cd <myApp> && npm install
```

and these run just fine. But when I get to the next step which is to either just run

```
gulp
```

or

```
node server
```

and nothing happens. If I run gulp then after it gets to the part where it says

```
Finished 'development' after 6.15 μs
```

in the logs it just hangs there. If I run node server it just hangs and nothing else happens. In either case I see nothing at

http://localhost:3000/

Is this a common sticking point for people?

Comment: Just to be sure...you do have all the prerequisites installed, right?

Comment: Yup. Double checked. Still the same issue.

Comment: did you do bower install?

Comment: I just ran the install for mean io and when it finished I ran gulp and it works fine.  I then shutdown that server and ran npm start and it ran fine too.  Something apparently did not 'run just fine'.

Comment: if you want to learn MEAN though, I would start with this:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application